# Bash script returning "Not found" error

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script to get the latest file from a directory for backup purposes. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -u
set -e

backup_dir=/media/backup

cd $backup_dir

tar_file= $(ls -Art | tail -n 1)

#ls -Art | tail -n 1

echo $tar_file
```

When I run the script it gets the right file but also returns a not found error and I don't know why:

```
./backup: 10: 20130403-120001.tar.gz: not found
```

I tested it with the line that's commented out, not putting it as a variable and that works without throwing an error so it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space after the `=`:

```
tar_file=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
```

With the space, the line is interpreted as assigning nothing to `$tar_file` and running the command that is obtained as the output of the `$(...)`. That command is not found.

Comment: Wow such a simple mistake, thanks for the explanation of what happens as well!

Answer (score 2):

Is it correct to have

```
tar_file= $(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
```

and not

```
tar_file=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
```

?

(mind the space)

Comment: Thanks man, I'm going to mark choroba's answer as correct just because he gave an explanation of what the space does to the code, thanks all the same though!